# Creating a smaller array from a larger array in python, based on values in one column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large numpy array (with 2 columns) which I would like to reduce to a smaller array, based only on specific values in the 2nd column (ie when it is <0.5).

Based on the answer by Asagen below, here is my script:

```
ozone=np.array(ozone_1, float)
time=np.array(dectime_1)
a=np.column_stack((ozone, time))
b=a[a[:,1]==a[0,1]]
c=np.nanmean(b[:,0])
```

Comment: Look into [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
foo = np.random.uniform(0,1,20).reshape(10,2)
bar = foo[foo[:,1]<0.5]
```